# JavaScript get all elements by class name, while excluding specific classes?

Tags: javascript, html

So let's say I have the following website:

```
<div class="hello"></div>
<div class="hello"></div>
<div class="hello world"></div>
<div class="hello"></div>
```

Using the following code, I save all elements that have the class "hello" into an array:

`var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('hello');`

Is there any way I can exclude all elements that have the class "world" so I can only get three results?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Theoretically you can use `document.querySelectorAll()`

```
// searches for all <div> elements with the class of 'hello',
// and without the class of 'world':
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('div.hello:not(.world)');
```

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('div.hello:not(.world)');
console.log(inputs);
```

```html
<div class="hello"></div>
<div class="hello"></div>
<div class="hello world"></div>
<div class="hello"></div>
```

Or you can simply convert the `NodeList` into an array, and filter that array:

```
// searches for all elements with the class-name of 'hello':
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('hello'),

    // Array.prototype.slice.call(inputs,0) uses the Array
    // method of slice on the NodeList returned by
    // document.getElementsByClass(), turning it into an
    // Array:
    inputsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(inputs, 0)
                    // then we filter the Array:
                    .filter(function (el) {
                      // el: a reference to the current
                      //     Array element of the Array
                      //     over which we're iterating.

      // el.classList.contains returns a Boolean
      // true if the 'el' contains a class of
      // 'world', and false if not; we invert that
      // using the ! (not) operator because
      // Array.prototype.filter() retains elements
      // should the evaluation be true/truthy;
      // whereas we want to keep the elements for
      // which classList.contains() is false:
      return !(el.classList.contains('world'));
    });
```

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('hello'),
  inputsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(inputs, 0).filter(function(el) {
    return !(el.classList.contains('world'));
  });

console.log(inputsArray);
```

```html
<div class="hello"></div>
<div class="hello"></div>
<div class="hello world"></div>
<div class="hello"></div>
```

Answer (score 11):

Use `querySelectorAll`.

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.hello:not(.world)')
```

Comment: did you mean querySelectorAll

Comment: @evilive thans and corrected.